# auto-login and hidden-users in lightdm

Tags: auto-login

I edited `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` to include users I don't want to see at login screen when booting. However, they appear in the login screen. Then I restart Ubuntu system rather than entering password. So this second time auto-login attempt is successful. The system is booting up as expected. I don't know why auto-login attempt is not working at the first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Most programs only read their configuration files when they are started or restarted. Rebooting your system forced lightdm to start again, and it then read its configuration file so your changes took effect.